# Blender Object loses Alignment during Rotation (Only During Render)

Tags: rendering

I have a blender object which animates / rotates along the z axis just fine in the viewport:

[image: viewport]

However, when I render it in either Eevee or Cycles, the object (hilariously) loses alignment and breaks apart:

[image: blender render]

Can anyone help me figure out what's the cause of this really strange behaviour at render time?

Edit: deleted all my rendering configs.  Issue was caused by original object overlapping with my Collection Instance and showing up on render. I had to hide the original object in order to make it work on render.

cake model comes from [here](https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/food/fruit/desserts)

Comment: Does this object have any render-time displacement?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I don't believe so.  I've attached my additional settings from different screens in the original post.

Comment: this is where I got the original cake model and brought it into my own scene: https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/food/fruit/desserts

Comment: It seems like you have two of these objects in the Scene, and the second one is disabled from viewport visibility, but not rendering.

Comment: ... model on the provided link is OK, also you can delete your huge screens of render setup, they have nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: @vkliidu might be onto it.. make sure you have no objects hidden in the viewport, but visible to the render.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you vklidu and Robin Betts!  It was showing my original object + Collection instance and overlapping them. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused by original object overlapping with my Collection Instance and showing up on render. I had to [hide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129687/how-to-render-a-collection-instance-but-not-the-original-collection-in-blender-2) the original object in order to make it work on render.